# Sharing root data with router-view component vue js

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Best to give more context to this first.

I am creating an Single Page Application with vuejs, vue-router. When the user logs in the user object is returned from the backend. I am using Laravel 5.4 for the backend. The user object is then sorted on the vue `$root` instance so it can be accessed anywhere by using `this.$root.user`.

My only problem is that when I want to edit the user data, I have an edit form in which the user data should be automatically populated with the existing data. This would be fine if I just wanted to do something like this: `v-model="this.$root.user.first_name"` but I have a form object which helps with validation and making everything more modular.

So in the `data` return I have this on the router-view component:

```
data: function() {
        return {
            form: new Form({
                first_name: this.$root.user.first_name,
                last_name: this.$root.user.last_name,
                country: this.$root.user.country,
                preferred_currency: this.$root.user.preferred_currency,
                email: this.$root.user.email,
            })
        }
    }
```

The only problem is that everything is undefined. I'm not sure how to get around the problem so any help which be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way to do it.

What I forgot to add is that on refresh of the page obviously vue forgets about all of the current stored data so because of that I have to make a request to the backend to get the current user.

So when the ajax request is made to get the current user I created a new Vue object in which all objects can see and assigned it to `Window.Event` and created a new Vue instance against that. `Window.Event = new Vue({});`

Now once the ajax request has returned I did `Window.Event.$emit('user', this.user)` and on the component which needed the user data I just created an `$on` event with `create()`.

```
created() {
        Window.Event.$on('user', function(user){
            this.form.first_name = user.first_name
            this.form.last_name = user.last_name
            this.form.country = user.country
            this.form.preffered_currency = user.preffered_currency
            this.form.email = user.email
        }.bind(this));
    }
```